# Retrieve integers by looping through a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, loops, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

Can someone show me how to retrieve values by looping through a `NSMutableArray`? My code, which basically adds integer numbers to the array, is below :

```
NSMutableArray *ptr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[ptr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[ptr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
[ptr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];

 // How to retrieve them as integers?
```

I'm trying to retrieve each number from the array and sum them up to a total value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its actually pretty simple:

```
int totalValue = 0;
for(NSNumber *number in myArray) // Use fast enumeration to iterate through the array
{
    totalValue += [number intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie so my answer may be wrong, but try this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0, i < [ptr count], i++){
int value = [[ptr objectAtIndex:i] intValue] //you get the int, integerValue is applicable for NSInteger
sum = sum + value;//you adding values
}
```

Comment: Change intvalue to intValue and it should work. FWIW, apparently you forgot to put an empty line before the code.

Comment: You've got a number of syntax errors, but other than that this would work. JustSid's answer, using [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) is more idiomatic, however.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < [ptr count]; i++){`